# Como saber se um arquivo é oculto em C++

Tags: c, c++

Existe alguma forma de saber se um arquivo é oculto em C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Windows

Em windows pode fazer uso da função [`GetFileAttributesA`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa) para obter informaçoes sobre o arquivo. O retorno são os próprios atributos na forma de flags, na qual eu mostro apenas a parte inicial da lista:

- `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE`
- `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED`
- `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE`
- `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`
- `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED`
- `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`

Tem toda a lista disponivel em https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants

A utilização disto em código isto resulta em algo como:

```
DWORD atributos = GetFileAttributesA(meu_arquivo);
if (atributos != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && (atributos & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)){
    //escondido
}
```

Como a função pode retornar `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` foi necessário contemplar isso no if, mas a parte importante é verificar para a flag de oculto com `atributos & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`.

O nome do arquivo fornecido à função, no meu exemplo como `meu_arquivo`, vai ser na essência um ponteiro para char.

Existem algumas alternativas à função que indiquei com diferenças na codificação e informação obtida:

- [GetFileAttributesA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa) - Informação essencial em Ansi
- [GetFileAttributesExA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexa) - Informação extra em Ansi
- [GetFileAttributesW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw) - Informação essencial em Unicode
- [GetFileAttributesExW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw) - Informação extra em Unicode

## Sistemas Unix

Em sistemas unix pode verificar pelo nome do seu arquivo. Se contem um `.` no inicio, que já indica que o mesmo é oculto.

Em código isto reflete-se a verificar se o primeiro caratere é `.` acedendo ao indice zero:

```
if (meu_arquivo[0] == '.'){
    //meu_arquivo é oculto
}
```

Note que isto vai funcionar corretamente quer o nome do arquivo esteja representado através de um `char[]` ou uma `std::string`.

Comment: é 100% certo que um arquivo com '.' no inicio do nome é oculto?

Comment: Sempre que obtêm o nome do arquivo por qualquer mecanismo que obtenha arquivos de uma diretoria sim. Ou seja por outras palavras, desde que não seja você a escrever o nome do ficheiro manualmente sim é garantido.